# play framework cache annotation

Tags: caching, annotations, playframework-2.0, ehcache

Can somebody exlain, with a sample, how works the cache annotation in play framework 2 in java
I would like to cache the result of the method with his parameters; something like this:

```
@Cache(userId, otherParam)
public static  User getUser(int userId, String otherParam){
return a User from dataBase if it isn't in cache.
}
```

Maybe a tutorial is available?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Cached` annotation doesn't work for every method call. It only works for Actions and moreover, you can't use parameters as a cache key (it's only a static `String`). If you want to know how it works, look at the [`play.cache.CachedAction`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/cache/CachedAction.java) source code.

Instead, you will have to use either `Cache.get()`, check if result is null and then `Cache.set()` or  the `Cache.getOrElse()` with a `Callable` with a code like :

```
public static User getUser(int userId, String otherParam){
    return Cache.getOrElse("user-" + userId + "-" + otherParam, new Callable<User>() {
        @Override
        public User call() throws Exception {
            return getUserFromDatabase(userId, otherParam);
        }
    }, DURATION);
}
```

Be careful when you construct your cache keys to avoid naming-collision as they are shared across the whole application.